# How refresh a Flatlist with Input's text using Json API

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, native-base

I'm trying to refresh the Flatlist when a user type something in the search bar, but I don't know exactly how to do it.

The goal here is to display all french county returned by the API and when you enter something in the search bar the API will return only certain county

I'm using NativeBase and Axios

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet, StatusBar, ListView, FlatList} from 'react-native'
import { } from 'react-navigation'
import { Container, Header, Title, Content, Footer, FooterTab, Button, Left, Right, Body, Icon, Text, List, ListItem, Spinner, Toast, Root, Input, Item } from 'native-base';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Directions } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export default class Home extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data : null,
      departement : ""
    }
    this.fetchDepartements();
  }

  fetchDepartements() {
    axios.get('http://192.168.1.12/APIGSBPraticien.php?departement=' + this.state.departement).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
      this.setState({data : response.data})
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <ListItem>
        <Text>{item.PRA_Departement==null ? "Code Postal: " + item.PRA_CP:item.PRA_Departement}</Text>
      </ListItem>
    )
  }

  handleSearch = (text) => {
    console.log(text);
    this.setState({departement: text}),
    () => { this.fetchDepartements}
  };

    render() {
      if (this.state.data === null) {
        return(
          <Container style={{marginTop: 20}}>
          <StatusBar translucent={false} />
          <Header>
            <Left>
              <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()} transparent>
                <Icon name='menu' />
              </Button>
            </Left>
            <Body>
              <Title>Accueil</Title>
            </Body>
          </Header>
          <Content>
          <Spinner style={{marginVertical:250}} color='green'/>
          </Content>
        </Container>
        )
      } else {
        return (
          <Root>
          <Container style={{marginTop: 20}}>
          <StatusBar translucent={false} />
          <Header>
            <Left>
              <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()} transparent>
                <Icon name='menu' />
              </Button>
            </Left>
            <Body>
              <Title>Accueil</Title>
            </Body>
          </Header>
          <Header searchBar rounded>
          <Item>
                <Icon name="search" />
                <Input onSubmitEditing={text => this.handleSearch(text)} placeholder="Rechercher ..." />
          </Item>
          </Header>
          <Content>
          <FlatList 
              data={this.state.data}
              renderItem={this.renderItem}
              keyExtractor={item => item.PRA_NUM}
              onEndReached={()=> Toast.show({
                text: 'Chargement terminé !',
                type: "success",
                textStyle: {marginHorizontal:100}
              })}
            />
          </Content>
        </Container>
        </Root>
        )
      }
    }
}
```

I tried to get the user's input ( handleSearch() ) and update the state but once done I want to refresh the Flatlist.

Comment: this will send requests to the server with every key input. The flatlist will update when you set new data from the server of which I think you are doing.

Comment: What I want to do is when something is entered in the input it will re-request `http://192.168.1.12/APIGSBPraticien.php?departement=` but with the text from the `<Input />` after `?departement=<Text from <Input>>` and refresh the flatlist

Comment: so what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: The problem is in the `onSubmitEditing` or `onTextChanged` what I wrote basically doesn't work, I already try to add something manually in the URL, and it's working(at the first start of the app) but when I'm entering something in the bar and confirm and when I log the result in `handleSearch` I obtain : [this](http://prntscr.com/nko7av) so I'm not sure if what I wrote (the handleSearch section) is correct, and when I update the state, is the <FlatList> suppose to refresh automatically when the data(of the state) is updated ??